# Tomcat started but application war file not deployed with the docker composer file

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, war, tomcat9

I use an image of tomcat-9 for adoptopenjdk. The docker-compose file config is:

```
tomcat-server:
    image: tomcat:9.0.45-jdk11-adoptopenjdk-hotspot
    ports: 
      - "8081:8080"
    volumes:
      - /webapp/target/app.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war
    environment:
      - EUREKA.CLIENT.SERVICEURL.DEFAULTZONE=http://naming-server:8761/eureka
      - SPRING.REDIS.HOST=redis-cache-server
```

When I start the tomcat using docker-compse file, the logs shows that it wont start with the port mentioned 8081. It is still started on 8080. See the logs for details.

```
tomcat-server_1       | NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.45
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 30 2021 10:29:04 UTC
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.45.0
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /opt/java/openjdk
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.10+9
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            AdoptOpenJDK
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.27] using APR version [1.6.5].
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020]
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [745] milliseconds
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war]
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war] has finished in [361] ms
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [463] milliseconds
```

I tried few things but not having any success.
Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Atul

Comment: can you share dockerfile for creating tomcat image? or you are using that image on dockerhub

Comment: I am using image from dockerhub.

Comment: Where are you telling Tomcat to listen on `8081`? If you are talking about the line in you compose file `8081:8080`, that's just port mapping. `8081` will be the port used on the host, not the container.

Comment: Ohh yes... my bad. Sorry got you @snahor. Thanks for clarification. Not sure how I missed it.

Comment: @snahor, one more question ... the war file is able to copy in tomcat-webapps folder but it wont execute. DO I need to add cammnad to execute. Because the docker file of image and command to run catelina.sh file.

Comment: Sorry, I won't be able to help you there, my tomcat knowledge is super limited (close to nothing). But according to your output, the war file was loaded. I believe you don't need to change anything.

Comment: Anyway thanks for clarification.

Comment: Why do you need to change the default port `8080`? Tomcat runs in a virtual container, there will be no port conflict. As snahor already remarked you have a mapping from port `8081` of your host to port `8080` of your container.

Comment: The war file is loading but wont install. Port issue is resolved, it was wrong perception.

Comment: The logs clearly shows that your WAR file was deployed (and automatically started). Can you explain why do you think it wasn't? If anything failed during the container start, it would show in the logs.

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz just added the answer. War was copied but not deployed. I mentioned my finding as well. Please check and suggest if I missed something or is there any better way to do it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the log message carefully: _"Deploying web application **directory**"_. Docker added the volume `/usr/loca/tomcat/webapps/app.war` as directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the issue. Solution is to create a separate docker file to create a tomcat image and used it in docker composer file.

The problem is, even the war is copied to webapps folder of tomcat it wont deploy. See the logs for reference:

```
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war]
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war] has finished in [361] ms
tomcat-server_1       | org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

As image **tomcat:9.0.45-jdk11-adoptopenjdk-hotspot** contains the command **['catalina.sh', 'run']**, as soon as the docker-compose command executes, the tomcat started and at the end of the starting process it copied war file to the tomcat location. So it wont deploy the war file.

This is the reason what I have found. (Please clear me if I am wrong ot I missed anything).

So final solution is like this(which worked for me):

Create a docker file. (e.g.- Dockerfile_web)

```
#Take the Tomcat-9 image which supports AdoptOpenJDK
FROM tomcat:9.0.45-jdk11-adoptopenjdk-hotspot

#Copy the WAR file to tomcat
ADD ./webapp/target/attest.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/attest.war

#Allow execution (Not required, just added)
CMD chmod +x /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh
```

Next is to add this file reference in docker-compose file.

```
web-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_Web
    ports: 
      - "8081:8080"
    networks:
      - app-network
    command: ['catalina.sh', 'run']
    environment:
      - EUREKA.CLIENT.SERVICEURL.DEFAULTZONE=http://naming-server:8761/eureka
      - SPRING.REDIS.HOST=redis-cache-server
```

Once I run this with **docker-compose up** it started and working as expexcted.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, war file was extracting but wasn't deploying, also there was not error or warning in the docker logs. After debugging the issue for two days, I changed the docker image of tomcat and it worked for me.

Previously I was using tomcat:9.0.80-jdk17-corretto-al2 and after changing it to tomcat:latest it started working flawlessly.